# Reading a file from Eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, io

I need to read an XML file and parse the data. For that, I have placed the file FoodItemData.xml in the Eclipse project as shown in the image below.

[image: Directory structure]

I used the following code to read the file and create a new File object for manipulation.

```
URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("FoodItemData.xml");
File file = new File(url.getPath());
```

When I debug I see the `url` as `/D:/Application/Workspaces/Practice/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/CreationalPatterns/WEB-INF/classes/FoodItemData.xml`

I need to know whether this code will fail if I import this project in another computer as a WAR file. That is, if the file is read in another computer since the URL I see is of my local system's.

If it fails, how do I rectify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  code will NOT fail as you have not hardcoded the path of your file. As you are using the class loader to find the file, so it will finally look for file in the classes directory of the application. The base path will be fetched in respect to the web server root context. If FoodItemData.xml is present in your WEB-INF/classes directory then you should be able to fetch it, no matter which machine you are using to execute the code.